# Access autocad object properties without opening it by VBA

Tags: vba, autocad

I have been using folder browser for VBA, I could paste the code of it, but bottom line is that I get returned file name as a string.
Is there any way to access drawing properties (i.e number of layouts) without open?

```
Public Sub TestFileDialog()
    dwgname = FileBrowseOpen("C:", "*", ".dwg", 1) 'dwgname is typeof string
End Sub
```

Its only the first step (use of FileBrowseOpen function is shown, but also i can use FolderBrowse and collect all .dwg inside of folder),actually i had in mind to batch export all layouts of selected .dwgs to currenty open one. Is there any chance for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To effectively read a .dwg file you'll need to open AutoCAD, otherwise the information is not accessible. Some properties may be, such as author, but not number of layouts...

But you can use AutoCAD Console (accoreconsole.exe) to run a headless AutoCAD and use APIs to read any information you need. This is really fast for reading lot's of files and the user will not see it running (but it needs to be installed anyway).

http://aucache.autodesk.com/au2012/sessionsFiles/3338/3323/handout_3338_CP3338-Handout.pdf

Answer (score 1):

you could stay in VBA and use ObjectDBX
it leads to a very similar approach as accoreconsole.exe on in .NET does, i.e you won't see any drawing open in UI since it works on the database itself
It requires adding library reference (Tools->References) to "AutoCAD/ObjectDBX Common XX.Y Type Library", where "XX.Y" is "19.0" for AutoCAD 2014
a minimal functioning code is

```
Sub main()

Dim myAxDbDoc As AxDbDocument
Dim FullFileName As String

FullFileName = "C:\..\mydrawing.dwg"  '<== put here the full name of the file to be opened
Set myAxDbDoc = AxDb_SetDrawing(FullFileName)
MsgBox myAxDbDoc.Layers.Count

End Sub



Function AxDb_SetDrawing(FullFileName As String) As AxDbDocument
Dim DBXDoc As AxDbDocument

Set DBXDoc = Application.GetInterfaceObject("ObjectDBX.AxDbDocument.19") '<== place correct AutoCAD version numeber ("19" works for AutoCAD 2014)

On Error Resume Next
DBXDoc.Open FullFileName
If Err <> 0 Then
    MsgBox "Couldn't open" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & FullFileName, vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "AxDB_SetDrawing"
Else
    Set AxDb_SetDrawing = DBXDoc
End If
On Error GoTo 0

End Function
```

Still, you must have one AutoCAD session running from which make this sub run! But you should have it since talked about "currently open" drawing